# ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to code a simple recommender system using only pandas and I am having trouble with the filtering part.I want to select all the rows where the RatingCounts column is greater than a value I choose.This returns me a dataframe with one column filled with the correct booleans but i cannot index my data with this selection it gives me a value error as mentioned in the title.Here is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`selection` appears to be a 2D DataFrame with 1 column, `RatingCounts`. 
The error occurs [when you pass a 2D indexer](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1083) to `DataFrame.loc`. 
You can avoid the error by passing a 1D boolean indexer to `DataFrame.loc`:

```
final_data.loc[selection['RatingCounts']]
```

Comment: Thank you this has been helpful but I needed to use .ravel() in the end to turn that numpy.ndarray into a one dimensional array.

Comment: Yes, it is hard to understand your exact situation without code to reproduce it. In the future you may be able to get more accurate answers by providing a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This helped me solve a bug. Some newly added code upstream from where the error was being thrown added a new column that happened to have the same name as an existing column in my dataframe. The error was then thrown when I tried to filter on that column because now there were two columns which created a 2 column dataframe rather than a single series.
I solved this by renaming the new column to eliminate the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly get this error if you have multi lvl column indexing.

EX.:

- How to create the error by renaming columns

```
existing_df.columns = [['user','movie','ratings']]
```

- How to it correctly

```
existing_df.columns = ['user','movie','ratings']
```